# Induction pattern

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My teacher asked us this question just as a thought, but I don't understand how to even approach it.

If I were to have an equation and proved P(1), P(2) and $\forall n, \in $ $\mathbb N$ $P(n) \rightarrow P(2*n)$ are true, then would $\forall n, \in $ $\mathbb N$ $P(n)$ be true?

I know the usual step would be to prove $P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1) $. Would that mean that you still wouldn't have proven that step, and thus it would be false.

I was also wondering if there was a way to come up with examples disproving them if they were false. I can't even think of an equation that fits the requirement.

Comment: It seems like you'd only ever be able to show that P(2^n) is true, for all n. But using the method you stated, could you even show P(3) holds? I don't think so...

Comment: $P(n)= n \ne 3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would $P(3)$ be forced to be true?

You can have other induction patterns.  Maybe there are different proofs for odd and even numbers.  You might prove $P(1), P(2), P(n) \implies P(n+2)$, which would suffice.  I vaguely remember one that proved $P(1), P(2^n)\implies P(2^{n+1})$ and then stepped downward from $P(2^{n+1})$ to $P(2^n+1)$

Comment: Does that mean generally, induction patterns of $P(n) \rightarrow P(Xn)$ where X is just some integer usually can't work?

Comment: Not by themselves.  If you start with $P(1)$ you get $P(X^k)$ but nothing more.  Coupled with other patterns they can work, as I indicated.